# Product rule for integration???

Tags: integration

Knowing that there is a product rule for differentiating things, how would a product rule work in reverse?

For instance, how would you go around integrating $8x^3(3x-1)^2$?

At school, we haven't learn a rule to solve this at all from my teachers, and coming across a question like this, I couldn't answer it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you learned about Integration By Parts?

Comment: You could also distribute $8x^3(3x-1)^2$ into $72x^5-48x^4+8x^3$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int fdg=fg-\int gdf$$
where $df$ denotes the derivative of $f$, so $df(x)=f'(x)dx$. Howerever in this exercise the best idea is just to do the multiplication, as you are simply integrating polynomials.